# How to convert between lux and exposure value?

Tags: c, algorithm, light, photography

How to convert from an [exposure value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value#EV_as_a_measure_of_luminance_and_illuminance) to [lux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux)? Thanks!

i.e. what's the formula behind [this chart](http://www.sekonic.com/support/support_2.asp)?

Comment: Which programming language do you want to achieve this ?

Comment: c-like langage is fine. or just the pointer to the mathematics involved will be appreciated.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Forget the math on Wikipedia. By inspecting the table to which you linked, it's possible to see a pattern:

```
EV      Lux
-1      1.25
-0.5    1.75
0       2.50
0.5     3.50
1       5.00
1.5     7.00
2       10.00
2.5     14.00
3       20.00
3.5     28.00
4       40.00
...
```

1 EV is 5 Lux. 2 EV is 10 Lux. 3 EV is 20 Lux. So, it looks logarithmic:

```
lux = (2 ^ ev) * 2.5;
```

(2 to the power of EV, times 2.5)

C-like:

```
#include <math.h>

double evToLux(double ev) {
    return pow(2, ev) * 2.5;
}
```

**Update**

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value#EV_as_a_measure_of_luminance_and_illuminance) has this formula:
[image]

**Update 2**

> It is important to point out that EV is dependent on the film speed (ISO). All above is true only for ISO 100. It is easy to convert to other speeds, though: `EV(at ISO 100) == EV(at ISO 200) - 1`

(H/T Nikolai Ruhe)

Comment: It is important to point out that EV is dependent on the film speed (ISO). All above is true only for ISO 100. It is easy to convert to other speeds, though: `EV(at ISO 100) == EV(at ISO 200) - 1`